# failed to resolve com.android.support.recylerview-v7:23.1.0

Tags: android

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sandy.carddemo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
 compile ("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.+")
 compile ("com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:23.1.0")
 compile ("com.android.support.cardview-v7:23.1.0")
}
```

This Is my app.gradle file. I have installed all dependencies but it still gives

> failed to resolve  com.android.support.recylerview-v7:23.1.0
>
> failed to resolve  com.android.support.cardview-v7:23.1.0

Answer (score 3):

Your dependency declaration is incorrect. Instead of:

```
compile ("com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:23.1.0")
compile ("com.android.support.cardview-v7:23.1.0")
```

It should be (adding colons):

```
compile ("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0")
compile ("com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0")
```

So, it is defined as:

```
compile ("<groupId>:<artifactId>:<version>")
```